# EXM Error - System.UriFormatException Message: Invalid URI

Tags: exm

I'm getting this error when trying to send an email campaign, so I've debuged the pipeline `Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.GenerateLink.SetServerUrl` and came to conclusion that the `LinkManager.GetItemUrl` for any email item is getting the following link:
https:///sitecore-modules/shell/Email/Messages/2019/12/19T10270075/Announcement

It seams that `hostname` is missing and this causes an exception when trying to create a new URI because of the extra slash, am I missing some configuration on EXM?

```
20160 10:33:09 ERROR Exception: System.UriFormatException Message:
Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. Source: System
    at System.Uri.CreateThis(String uri, Boolean dontEscape, UriKind uriKind)
    at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.HostnameMapping.HostnameMappingService.GetServerUrl(Item
item)
    at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Messages.HtmlMailBase.get_ServerUrl()
    at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Messages.HtmlMailBase.get_PreviewBaseUrl()
    at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Messages.HtmlMailBase.InsertEmailOpenedImg(Boolean
preview, String& html)
    at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Messages.WebPageMail.GetMessageBody(Boolean
preview)
    at Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Cm.MessageInfo.FillContentEditorInfo()
```

Comment: Are you sending EXM Campaign Programmatically ? Please check MailMessage Class

Comment: No, i'm using Sitecore EXM interface, and i've notice that im getting the same error on exm logs when i go to the Message tab of an Email Campaing, the message body preview is unavailable because of this.

Comment: have you set the Default Settings(on the dashboard , right hand side) and Domains List , if you are using Sitecore MTA.

Comment: Yes i've Base URL (https://sc93sc.dev.local), and i'm using custom stmp.

Comment: Create support ticket if not already done

Answer (score 2):

Do you have SXA installed? (or anything else that might have an impact on the linkprovider?)

I had the same issue with SXA installed and got a patch from Support. My issue was on 9.2 with SXA 1.9 after installing a patch - they did send me a new patch now. But I can reproduce the issue on a clean 9.3 setup with SXA as well. (9.3 probably had the change that was also in my patch which broke the link resolving)

Anyway.. as mentioned in the comments: ask Support for a patch as this is a bug. (unless you have a fully custom linkprovider that breaks it of course)